# grub2: how to bypass "press any key"?

Tags: linux, debian, grub2, uefi

I recently updated my motherboard and moved my grub2 onto EFI partition. I have same grub menu, but after I select a menu entry and press Enter, a message "Press any key" comes and the loading stops until I press any key. Is there any way to just tell grub2 to ignore any errors and do not block loading of an operating system?

Comment: Can you provide us a copy of your grub.cfg file? I'm wondering if you adjusted the partitions (i.e. hd(0,0)) correctly with the move.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a this tutorial titled: [GRUB 2 bootloader - Full tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html). This tutorial includes several screenshots where they're encountering "Press any key" messages.

#### For example

The GRUB error 13.

[image: ss of 13]

The GRUB Error 11 or GRUB Error 15:

[image: ss of 11]

In both cases the issue should be resolved by making sure that the OS entries in you're `grub.cfg` contain the correct references to the hard drive partition that they're suppose to be pointing to.

Typically you'll need to change references such as hd(0,0) to the correct partition's notation. Maybe hd(1,1) or something else.

Additionally the partition may be referenced by a UUID. If you're able to boot into the OS then do so and then when at a terminal prompt, type the command, `blkid` and note the UUID string for your particular HDD.

#### blkid example

```
$ blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="SYSTEM_DRV" UUID="10BE8345DE8CB0148" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="1053b90f-4685-4317-9dac-fbcf3002838f" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="av6WTb-69CU-4Ump-0fGR-dGbE-fTtC-fG93LA" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_root: UUID="75e07a5d-345d-453c-99bd-97fe615fd956" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_swap: UUID="93016bc7-8902-4ca8-82a4-13cffc7b4353" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_home: UUID="9b0bd0b8-9d75-467c-9694-98951325083d" TYPE="ext4"
```

Answer (score 0):

When the ***terminal --timeout=5 serial console***` line is added to your menu.lst grub configuration, your boot sequence will now show a series of "Press any key to continue" messages. If no key is pressed, the boot menu will appear on whichever (serial or console) appears first in the 'terminal' configuration line. The lines will look like this upon boot:

root-# ***Vi /boot/grub/grub.conf*** delete this line >
  ***terminal --timeout=5 serial console***

This should work